# SQL query to get horizontal table instead of vertical data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had three tables as below:

1. Table : tblAttribute

| Id | attribute | dcControl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LowTv |  |
| 2 | fastNozzle |  |
| 3 | LowNOx | PAR_LOW_NOX_ENG_ENABLE |
| 4 | TCCutOff |  |
| 5 | WHR |  |
| 6 | gtd311 |  |
| 7 | none |  |

2. Table : tblTuning

| id | eng_id | legislation | tuningMode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | T2 | Delta |
| 2 | 1 | T1 | Delta |
| 3 | 1 | T1 | LLT |
| 4 | 1 | T2 | LLT |
| 5 | 1 | T2 | Std |
| 6 | 1 | T1 | Std |
| 7 | 2 | T2 | Delta |
| 8 | 2 | T1 | Delta |
| 9 | 2 | T1 | LLT |
| 10 | 2 | T2 | LLT |
| 11 | 2 | T1 | Std |
| 12 | 2 | T2 | Std |

3. Table : tblTuningMatrix

| id | itemID | tuningattr_id | tuningattr_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 0 |

Now my query it to get the data from these three table is as below:

```
select tuning.id, tuning.eng_id,
    tuningMatrix.tuningattr_value, tuning.tuningMode,
    tuning.legislation, tuningAttribute.attribute,
    tuningAttribute.dcControl
from tuningMatrix
inner join tuning on tuning.itemId=tuningMatrix.itemID
inner join tuningAttribute on tuningAttribute.id=tuningMatrix.tuningattr_id
WHERE tuning.deleted = 'false'
```

Using above query I am getting data in vertical table. I want it as horizontal. What can I do?

Expected output is :

| id | eng_id | tuningMode | legislation | dcControl | LowTv | WHR | LowNox | TCCutOff | gtd311 | fastNozzle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Delta | T2 | null | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Actual Output:

| id | eng_id | tuningMode | legislation | dcControl | LowTv | WHR | LowNox | TCCutOff | gtd311 | fastNozzle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Delta | T2 |  | 1 | 0 | NULL | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | Delta | T2 | PAR_LOW_NOX_ENG_ENABLE | NULL | NULL | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | Delta | T2 |  | 0 | 0 | NULL | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | Delta | T2 | PAR_LOW_NOX_ENG_ENABLE | NULL | NULL | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Add expected sample output

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: From where you are referring the columns after `legislation` in the expected output

Comment: From 2nd table tblTuning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple PIVOT, but a conditional aggregation would offer more flexibility

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From (
        select tuning.id
              ,tuning.eng_id
              ,tuning.tuningMode
              ,tuning.legislation
              ,tuningAttribute.dcControl
              ,value = convert(int,tuningMatrix.tuningattr_value)
              ,tuningAttribute.attribute
         From tuningMatrix
         inner join tuning on tuning.itemId=tuningMatrix.itemID
         inner join tuningAttribute on tuningAttribute.id=tuningMatrix.tuningattr_id
         WHERE tuning.deleted = 'false'
      ) src
 Pivot ( max( value ) for attribute in ( [LowTv],[WHR],[LowNox],[TCCutOff],[gtd311],[fastNozzle] ) ) pvt
```

Comment: But I am not able to apply max() function on tuningattr_value because it's bit operand.

Comment: I had tried the same query and getting error like : Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar See update.  I just convert tuningattr_value to an INT